Implementing Transfer Learning to train a CNN Model for Distracted Driver Detection
I want to use EfficientNetB0 (or any other base models) from tensorflow.keras.applications to detect distracted drivers. The given dataset consists of approximately 22.5k training images, roughly classified into equal size of 10 sub classes.
Dataset URL: https://www.kaggle.com/c/state-farm-distracted-driver-detection/data
Implementation goes as follows:
IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH = 224, 224

# Load EfficientNetB0 with pre-trained weights, excluding the top classification layers
base_model = EfficientNetB0(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))

# Freeze the base model layers to retain pre-trained features
base_model.trainable = False

# Adding custom classification layers
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)  # Global pooling reduces feature maps to a vector
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)  # Dropout to prevent overfitting
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)  # Fully connected layer
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

# Defining the model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=outputs)

# Compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), 
              loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              metrics=["accuracy"])

# Defining callbacks
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='accuracy', factor=0.2, patience=3, min_lr=1e-6)

# Training the model
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr]
)

The above implementation achieved a mere accuracy of 0.1082, before callback.
Training ImageDataGenerator goes as follows:
train_dir = 'state-farm-distracted-driver-detection\\imgs\\train\\'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255.0,  # Normalize pixel values to [0, 1]
    rotation_range=20,    # Randomly rotate images by up to 20 degrees
    width_shift_range=0.2,  # Randomly shift images horizontally by 20% of the width
    height_shift_range=0.2,  # Randomly shift images vertically by 20% of the height
    shear_range=0.2,  # Apply shearing transformations
    zoom_range=0.2,   # Randomly zoom in/out by up to 20%
    horizontal_flip=True,  # Randomly flip images horizontally
    fill_mode="nearest"  # Fill empty pixels created during transformations
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                        train_dir,
                                                        target_size = (224, 224),
                                                        class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                        batch_size = 128
                                                    )

Before implementing Transfer Learning, I used a simple CNN Network of 3 sets of CNN() + MaxPooling() Layers, followed by a Flatten() and a Dense Layer, which achieved an accuracy of 0.8031 but performed poorly on the Testing Data. So, I wanted to use Transfer Learning Techniques for better accuracy, as well as validation accuracy.
I am open to use any alternative base models, if they provide better results.
New Update:
Upon further experimenting, I found out there was a problem in the Train ImageDataGenerator. It shows the best result, when the default library values were used for Pre-Processing the Images
Updated Train ImageDataGen:
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import preprocess_input
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

The same goes for the Test ImageDataGenerator.
Upon these changes, the model yielded an accuracy of 0.9737 and Val_Accuracy of 0.83909 (after fine tuning), which is a pretty decent result, I guess.
But, still I do not know the exact reason for this, is there any way for me to use a custom ImageDataGenerator Function / pass my own arguments?
